# Processing Minim | .loop() delay issue

Tags: loops, processing, delay, minim

I am currently making a very simple game, and I'm trying to add the music. The "theme" is a loop I created, but when I run the game there is a 1 second delay between the end of 1 loop and the start of the next one. I have tried changing the format and when I play the loop in other programs (iTunes, Audacity) it doesn't happen. I think it's a problem in processing itself, but just in case here is the important code:

```
    import ddf.minim.spi.*;
    import ddf.minim.signals.*;
    import ddf.minim.*;
    import ddf.minim.analysis.*;
    import ddf.minim.ugens.*;
    import ddf.minim.effects.*;

    Minim minim;
    AudioPlayer theme;

    void setup() {
     minim=new Minim(this);
     theme=minim.loadFile("Esquitoid.mp3");
     theme.loop();
    }

    void draw() {
    }
```

Comment: The mp3 may have some actual silence at the beginning or end that real music player programs are smart enough to skip.

Comment: Can you post a link to the mp3 file so we can test your code ourselves?

Comment: I've got the same problem! And Minim doesn't work with my WAV files at all ( :()